# Lemma B.1.3.2 in Johnstone's Sketches of an Elephant

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, topos-theory, algebraic-stacks

I'm having trouble understanding the proof of Lemma B.1.3.2 in Johnstone's Sketches of an Elephant. Let $\mathbb{C}:\mathcal{S}^{\mathrm{op}} \to \mathbf{Cat}$ be an indexed category, and denote by $\Pi: \mathcal{G}(\mathbb{C}) \to \mathbb{C}$ the associated Grothendieck fibration. For any morphism $(f,x): (I,A) \to (J,B)$ in $\mathcal{G}(\mathbb{C})$ the *vertical part* is defined to be $f$. Then Lemma 1.3.2 reads:

> **Lemma 1.3.2** Let $h: U \to V$ be a morphism of $\mathcal{G}(\mathbb{C})$. Then the vertical part of the factorisation of $h$ is an isomorphism iff, given any morphism $k: W \to V$ with the same codomain and factorisation $\Pi(k) = \Pi(h) \circ x$ of $\Pi(x)$ through $\Pi(h)$, there is a unique $l: W \to U$ in $\mathcal{G}(\mathbb{C})$ with $\Pi(l) = x$ and $hl = k$.

If the vertical part of $h$ is an isomorphism, then it is clear that the factorisation property holds.
Conversely, assuming the factorisation property, we write $h = (y,f)$, and set $k = (y,\mathrm{id})$, as suggested in the Elephant; as $x = \mathrm{id}$, we get $\Pi(k) = \Pi(h) \circ x$, so that there exists a unique morphism $g$ such that for $l = (\mathrm{id}, g)$ we get $hl = k$. Unwinding $hl = k$ we see that the composition of $y^*(B) \xrightarrow{g} \mathrm{id}^*(A) \xrightarrow{\mathrm{id}^*(f)} \mathrm{id}^* \circ y^*(B) \xrightarrow{\theta_{\mathrm{id},y}} y^*(B)$ is equal to the identity. Thus $f$ has right inverse because $\mathrm{id}^*(f)$ has one, but for the life of me I'm not able to verify that $f$ also has a left inverse. So my question is:

> Why does $f$ have a left inverse?

Comment: I don't understand most of what you're saying but you seem to be able to exhibit a right inverse, so you should probably try to prove that it's also a left inverse instead of trying to prove that "$f$ also has a left inverse".

Comment: If $\mathrm{id}^*(f)$ has a left inverse, then it is automatically equal to $g$, so the two statements are equivalent. I have tried fitting $\mathrm{id}^*(f)$ and $g$ into some different diagram, to show that $g$ is also a left inverse of $\mathrm{id}^*(f)$, but that didn't work. I have even tried showing that $g$ has a right inverse, which prove the statement, but that didn't work either.

Comment: I don't have a copy of the Elephant right now to check carefully your proof, but it seems to me that you used the factorisation property of $h$ against $k$, but you should also use the factorisation property of $k$ against $h$: indeed $k$ has tautologically the factorisation property because its vertical part is the identity. In Grothendieck terminology, you are trying to prove that cartesian morphisms above a fixed one are unique up to unique iso (kind of the same deal as proving that limits are so). I'll try to post a real answer tonight if time permits.

Comment: @Pece: Thank you for your suggestion! I hadn't thought of that. Unfortunately, if we use the factorisation property of $k$ against $h$, we get a morphism $m = (\mathrm{id}, a): U \to W$ (with $km = h$), and prove $f = \theta_{\mathrm{id},y} \circ h$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Claim:** The morphism $g$ is prone (usually called *Cartesian*).
*Proof:* Both $h$ and $k$ are prone (as pointed out by Pece), so that $l$ must also be prone (see e.g. Prop. 3.4 in [Vistoli's notes on stacks](http://homepage.sns.it/vistoli/descent.pdf)).

**Corollary:** The morphism $f$ is an isomorphism.
*Proof:* We already know that $g$ has a left inverse, namely $\mathrm{id}^*(f) \circ \theta_{\mathrm{id},y}$, and we have shown in the above discussion that prone morphisms have a right inverse, so that $g$ is an isomorphism. As isomorphisms satisfy the "2-out-of-3" property, we know that $\mathrm{id}^*(f)$ is an isomorphism, and therefore also $f$.